# Is it possible to apply regex pattern with OCR scanning in VisionKit?

Tags: coreml, visionkit

I need to draw CGRect around GUIDs. GUID pattern is easy but how to highlight it in real-time?
Now I have working scanner. I can extract GUID on `dataScanner` delegate. But how to draw CGRect around it in real time?

I'm not stuck with VisionKit and can try CoreML. Any thoughts about that?